# Simple PHP time date script

Tags: php, timezone

I am a PHP beginner and can't seem to get time script working

I need a simple PHP script that checks the local time of the user and
shows a message based on user's current time or global time GMT + 6 (Kyrgyzstan)

if time is between 24 - 11.10, then message 1 and echo time

if time is between 11.10 - 24, message 2 and echo time

please help

script is targeted and should treat all users as coming from a specific timezone GMT+6 (Kyrgyzstan)

Comment: to acomplish this you need to use javascript to get client date, an javascript ajax call to make a xml http request to php script, and you will get the response and show it to the client. For more information about ajax and javascript look http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ and http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: also it's simply to use jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, but it's good to know basic concept about ajax and javascript

Comment: i think it all can be accomplished with PHP since the time is local GMT+6 and it should all users as coming from GMT+6 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need users local time, it is possible to do sth like:

```
$message = '';
$now = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('KGT'));
if(intval($now->format('G')) > 11) {
    $message = 'msg1';
} else if(intval($now->format('G')) == 11 && intval($now->format('i')) > 10) {
    $message = 'msg1';
} else {
    $message = 'msg2';
}
echo $message;
```

If you pass users time via javascript you don't know timezone.. it depends on what you need..

Comment: but in my case it has be to later than 11.10 am. so will G format still work ?

Comment: G is 24-hour format, so it should - check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: so in my case i should do ...if(intval($now->format('G')) > 11.1).. ?

Comment: No, "G" stands for hours, "i" for minutes - check out code above. You can test it putting some time to \DateTime constructor i.e. '2013-10-13 11:11:01' instead of 'now'